# Django: Form Won't Add to Database

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I can add to the database from the admin page but the form in template won't save. When I try to submit the form it just refreshes the form.

views:

```
def newPost(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewPost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('myposts')
    else:
        form = NewPost()

    return render(request, 'create/new_post.html', {'title_page': 'New Post', 'form': form})
```

Template:

```
<form method="POST" class="input_group" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}

    <div class="submit_container">
            <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Form:

```
class NewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form_input_text'}))
    product = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form_input_select'}), choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES)
    caption_description = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form_input_text', 'style':'resize:none;', 'rows': '3'}))
    full_description = forms.CharField(max_length=2000, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form_input_text', 'style':'resize:none;'}), required=False)
    links = forms.CharField(max_length=2000, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form_input_text', 'style':'resize:none;'}), required=False)
    release_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'form_input_select_date'}, years=YEARS, empty_label="---"), required=False)
    display_image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form_img_btn'}))
```

Comment: What if you pass `request.FILES` to the form as well: `form = NewPost(request.POST, request.FILES)`?

Comment: Ah yes that works thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ImageField` is required as well, but you did not pass the `request.FILES` to the form, hence the form never receives any images, and thus assumes you did not submit any image.

You should pass both `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to the form:

```
def newPost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #                pass request.FILES ↓
        form = NewPost(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('myposts')
    else:
        form = NewPost()
    return render(request, 'create/new_post.html', {'title_page': 'New Post', 'form': form})
```